# how to animate a slider that uses setstate to change images in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am rather new to flutter and specially flutter animations. I am creating a custom slider that takes a list of URLs and creates NetworkImages from that URLs. also I have some dot indicators that change according to the image that is showing. how can I animate the image transition and the dot transition?

here is my code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> imageList;
  CustomSlider({this.imageList});
  @override
  _CustomSliderState createState() => _CustomSliderState();
}

class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  int photoIndex = 0;
  void _previousImage() {
    setState(() {
      photoIndex = photoIndex > 0 ? photoIndex - 1 : 0;
    });
  }

  void _nextImage() {
    setState(() {
      photoIndex = photoIndex < widget.imageList.length - 1
          ? photoIndex + 1
          : photoIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(widget.imageList[photoIndex]),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    height: 400.0,
                    width: 300.0,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 375.0,
                    left: 25.0,
                    right: 25.0,
                    child: SelectedPhoto(numberOfDots: widget.imageList.length, photoIndex: photoIndex),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Next'),
                  onPressed: _nextImage,
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Prev'),
                  onPressed: _previousImage,
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
  }
}
class SelectedPhoto extends StatelessWidget {

  final int numberOfDots;
  final int photoIndex;

  SelectedPhoto({this.numberOfDots, this.photoIndex});

  Widget _inactivePhoto() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 3.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 8.0,
          width: 8.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _activePhoto() {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 3.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 10.0,
          width: 10.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                blurRadius: 2.0
              )
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildDots() {
    List<Widget> dots = [];

    for(int i = 0; i< numberOfDots; ++i) {
      dots.add(
        i == photoIndex ? _activePhoto(): _inactivePhoto()
      );
    }

    return dots;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: _buildDots(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the image transition to be fade in and the dot transition to be like this:

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/563824/screenshots/2658319/untitled-28.gif

any ideas?

Comment: take a look at this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper

Comment: thanks, how should I pass the list of images to it? @MazinIbrahim

Comment: It has an `itemBuilder` and `itemCount` options similar to `ListView.Builder`

Comment: You should try to use [Lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie). Lottie is a mobile library for Android, iOS and Flutter that parses Adobe After Effects animations exported as json with Bodymovin and renders them natively on mobile!